Why is FileOutputStream throwing FileNotFoundException after createNewFile() in the ExternalFilesDir?
For the record, I am not personally able to replicate this problem, but I have seen my colleague's Android device trigger our custom error message associated with this exception and code.
From within a Fragment, the relevant code is:
File myDir = requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File myFile = new File(myDir, "temp.jpg");
myFile.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fstream = new FileOutputStream(myFile);

createNewFile() is not throwing any exception, so the file MUST already exist or been successfully created, and getExternalFilesDir means that I'm reading/writing to a file that my app owns, so it "can't" be a permissions problem.
What else could be going on? Frankly I'm stumped as to how it's even possible for this error to be getting thrown, given the file path. (For the record, I do have android.permissions.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in our manifest, even though it's not relevant to this scenario.)
Also, he's using SDK Level 33 and I'm Level 32, but I don't think that's relevant either, given the functions being called here.

FWIW, createNewFile() is pointless, especially in this situation. Beyond that, it might be worth an experiment to switch to requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(null) and see if that works better.
